# Checking the operating region of a MOSFET in an LTspice DC circuit

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, spice, saturation

I have a relatively complex circuit made of several nMOS and pMOS for which I am performing a `.op` analysis. This results in a list of the transistors' voltages and currents, from which I could manually check if each corresponding transistor is in linear or saturation regime.

This is a very tedious operation, especially considering that LTspice already knows the state of each component during the simulation. Is there a way to access that information without having to recalculate it by hand?

Comment: AFAIK, it can't be done within ltspice. Some post processing is needed. I do it with awk.

Comment: What LEVEL are your MOSFET models?  Or are they all VDMOS?

Comment: They're all level 1 and used for small signal amplification

Comment: I just noticed your comment.  You have to use @stekulov to tag me within the comment so I get a notification.  I don't have to do it for you because notifications are automatic to question/answer authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to do this, but there is a somewhat clunky method that might suit your needs.  If you're using LEVEL=1 or VDMOS (which uses LEVEL=1 underneath) MOSFET models, the conditions for the linear region versus the saturation region are quite simple.  Assuming `GAMMA`, the body-effect parameter, is zero (which implies \$V_{TH}=V_{T0}\$) and the device is not in cutoff (\$V_{GS} > V_{T0}\$), then:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Linear Region:} &V_{DS} < V_{GS} - V_{T0} \\
&\text{Saturation Region:} &V_{DS} \geq V_{GS} - V_{T0} \\
\end{align}
$$

You can use `.op` labels and [Waveform Arithmetic](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Waveform_Arithmetic.htm) boolean operations to create an expression which mimics the above conditions for each MOSFET instance.  It will be a little cumbersome to set up at first (especially with the node labeling), but after that upfront work you can get the `.op` labels to spit out a `0` or a `1` corresponding to the linear or saturation regions after each simulation run.  Below is the simplest example I can come up with.  You will require a more complicated expression if you want to be able to flag the cutoff or reverse conduction regions too.  I had to do one more trick to be able to use the parameterized \$V_{T0}\$ in the expressions.  That's what the two bonus voltage sources off to the right side do.  If you can get by with "hardcoding" \$V_{T0}\$ in each expression you won't have to do that trick.

[image]

What this `.op` simulation shows is that M2 is in the saturation region and M1 is in the linear region.